# Dynamic import with exception handling

Tags: python

I would like to load variables from another python moduled for analysis purposes.

Since there are hundreds of modules to analyze, I wrote a little script to automate the process.

However some of the modules throw exceptions during import. I can catch the exceptions but in case of an error I don't get anything from the module, not even valid objects.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import sys
import importlib

try:
    new_module = importlib.import_module("imported")
    print(new_module.__dict__.keys())
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

This is an example module to be imported:
imported.py:

```
a = 1
b = 1 / 0     # DivisionByZero Exception
```

Is there a way to get the variable a even if an exception occurs while importing imported.py?

Comment: What exactly are you doing analysis-wise though? Remember importing modules will also execute all code in them, so be careful to not do this with untrusted modules.

Answer (score 1):

If an error occurs, wrap the code in a try-except block.

```py
import re
import os
from importlib import import_module
from traceback import format_exc

INDENT = ' ' * 4


def wrap_try_except_block(module_file, new_file):
    with open(module_file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    code = 'try:\n{0}{1}\nexcept:\n{2}pass'.format(INDENT, ('\n' + INDENT).join(lines), INDENT)
    with open(new_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(code)


def get_module_path(module_name, tb_message):
    p = re.compile("File\s\"(.+?/)(" + re.escape(module_name) + ')(.py)\"')
    return list(p.search(tb_message).groups())


def get_module_variables(module_name):
    try:
        variables = import_module(module_name).__dict__.keys()
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        raise
    except Exception:
        tb_message = format_exc()
        module_path = get_module_path(module_name, tb_message)
        tmp_path = module_path.copy()

        tmp_module_name = module_name + '__tmp__'
        tmp_path[1] = tmp_module_name

        wrap_try_except_block(''.join(module_path), ''.join(tmp_path))
        variables = import_module(tmp_module_name).__dict__.keys()
        os.remove(''.join(tmp_path))

    return variables


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_module_variables('imported'))
```

**Output:**

```
dict_keys(['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', 'a'])
```

Comment: Good answer! Thanks! Somehow the regex to get the module path from the traceback did not work for me, though.

Comment: Well after trying it out a bit I had to realize that wrapping the whole script in a try-except block doesn't help with getting any variables after the exception, unfortunately.

Comment: If you want to get variables after the exception, see the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That works well as a clean and useful solution. While I appreciate your first answer, I would rather go with AST as the best answer.
[AST Example](https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2018/decipher-python-ast/) is a very helpful blog post, I found, for customizing the NodeVisitor